# Domain pointing to a wrong URL after performing a database "search and replace"

Tags: domains, wordpress, url

Upon migrating a WordPress site from development to production, I used Interconnectit's "Database Search and Replace Script in PHP" to update the site URL from `http://dev.example.com` to `http://example.com`

During the process, a script error popped up and I reloaded to do it again with false confidence. Now, `http://example.com` is pointing to `http://dev.dev.example.com`.

I tried to do seach/replace from `http://dev.dev.example.com` to `http://example.com`, but the string of `http://dev.dev.example.com` doesn't seem to exist.

If I access the site with a subdomain such as `http://example.com/about`, and can link to other subdomains such as `http://example.com/contact`.

Comment: Have you searched the database in phpMyAdmin or similar to see if the string exists and where?

Comment: Just download the SQL locally, load it up in your favourite text editor and do a search and replace using that.

Comment: "If I access the site with a subdomain such as `http://example.com/about`" - that's a _subdirectory_, not a _subdomain_. Is there supposed to be a question in your last sentence/paragraph?

Comment: "Now, `http://example.com` is pointing to `http://dev.dev.example.com`" - What do you mean exactly by that? Do you see a 3xx redirect from `example.com` to `dev.dev.example.com`? If you do then is that a single redirect or multiple redirects? Do the internal links contain `example.com` or `dev.dev.example.com`? What was the "script error"? If you were replacing `dev.example.com` with `example.com`, it's difficult to imagine how you would end up with `dev.dev.example.com` - unless the process was run in _reverse_?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL to find what your current system URL is in the database.

`SELECT * FROM wp_options where option_name in ('home','siteurl');` from PHPMyAdmin in CPanel.

This should show you what the system currently thinks your siteurl and home are.

Next, make a backup of your database before making any further changes.  You can do this via CPanel.

Next, follow the [instructions in this article](https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/) for fixing the URLs in wp_options, wp_posts, and wp_postmeta.

Rant:  I'm not trying to rub this in your face, but I will say this for anyone who reads this in the future.  Always make a copy of your database before making search/replace/update changes to your database.  The typical end user DB tools don't have Undo capability so changes are permanent.

It's also a good idea to keep a development AND a production copy of your databases.  I maintain both a production and development site so I can test changes in development before putting them into production.  To keep dev current, I periodically copy production over to development just so it has the most up to date data.